# Unable to convert tweets to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sentiment-analysis, rtweet

I extracted tweets between the dates of 2022-09-15 up to yesterday based on the search_30day function in the rtweet package, with the following:

```
install.packages("rtweet")
remotes::install_github("ropensci/rtweet@devel")
library("remotes")
library("rtweet")

consumer_key <- ""
consumer_secret <- ""
access_token <- ""
access_secret <- ""
app <- ""

token = rtweet::create_token(app,consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)
auth_get()
dataBTC1 <- search_30day("Bitcoin analysis", n = 100, env_name = "Tweets30", fromDate = "20220915000", toDate = "202209152359", parse = FALSE)
```

parse = FALSE, due to the package which needs to be updated and I already notified the maintainers. They are working on it. However, when I use the following:

```
btc.df <- twListToDF(dataBTC1)
```

I get:

```
Error in twListToDF(dataBTC1) : 
Elements of twList are not of an appropriate class
```

I have searched for help online, but nothing worked so far. I tried to use as.data.frame() and it did not work. However, when I look up thw class of dataBTC1 it gives me that it is a dataframe. So what can I do yo make it a data frame?

Comment: could you please share a sample of `dataBTC1` with `dput(dataBTC1)`. depending on the structure maybe `dput(head(dataBTC1))` might work.

Comment: I tried that, but I get a very long output.  It loks like it shows the exact same as it was in a dataframe but then without the frame around it.

This is what I get in the first sentence:

list(structure(list(created_at = c("Thu Sep 15 23:56:43 +0000 2022",....

and then the list goes on for  a while.

Comment: It turns out that dataBTC1 is a list, so I decided to unlist it by doing: 
```
df1 <- unlist(dataBTC1)
dfbtc1 <- as.data.frame(df1[1,99])
```
since the rows 1:99 belongs to the original twitter list 'created_at', however to do such manipulations to each element of the original twitter data(16 of them) and then for each day(30 days) takes too long. Is there an easier fix to do this? Perhaps by a for loop of something else?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can use the following:

```
dataBTC1 <- search_30day("Bitcoin analysis lang:en", n = 100, env_name = "Tweets30", fromDate = "20220915000", toDate = "202209152359", parse = FALSE)

##the above is a list check by class(dataBTC1) if it returns "list", then proceed

##convert to dataframe

dfbtc1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, dataBTC1)
```

Hope this helps other people as well!